# Use tablesorter jQuery plugin with YQL-generated table

Tags: jquery, yql

I'm trying to use the tablersorter jQuery plugin (www.tablesorter.com), but I can't get it to  work with a table that's dynamically populated via YQL from a Google Doc (using [Christian Heilmann's example](https://www.christianheilmann.com/2010/07/14/analyzing-the-fifa2010-worldcup-with-guardian-data-and-yql/))

I'm trying to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nbierma6/FFpS9/):

```
Results

Name    Team    Position    Time    Shots   six seven   eight
Abdoun  Algeria Midfielder  16      0       6   0       0   
Abe     Japan   Midfielder  351     0       101 14      0   
Abidal  France  Defender    180     0       91  6       0
```

I have tablesorter working in this example with a static table:

http://jsfiddle.net/nbierma6/KB5dQ/3/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `$("#results").tablesorter();` inside getJSON callback function, not after it. You are calling tablesorter() on results table *before* it is created.

Edit: You should also change `<td>` elements to `<th>` elements inside `<thead>` for sorting to work.

Comment: oops! missed that part. got it now. thanks!! http://jsfiddle.net/nbierma6/FFpS9/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to enable debugging in table sorter, it should give you an idea of why it is not working.

```
$("#results").tablesorter({  
    debug: true 
});
```